# LeafletJS remove duplicate addTo ()

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am just wondering does anybody know how to remove the duplicates {icon:Sheltericon} and addTo(Shelter) for each marker. I only need them to be mentioned once as I am including about a hundred markers.

```
       var Sheltericon = L.icon({

            iconUrl: 'hostel.png',
            iconSize:     [16, 28], 
            iconAnchor:   [8, 18], 
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -13] 


       });

       var Shelter = L.layerGroup();
       L.marker([51.894816, -8.474554] {icon:Sheltericon}).bindPopup('').addTo(Shelter);
       L.marker([51.894816, -8.474554], {icon:Sheltericon}).bindPopup('').addTo(Shelter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your adding points, is creating a group then adding them one at a time to the group. So you have to add them for each point. Finally you just add the Shelter to the map once, as it's acting as the layer.

Another option would be putting all the points into a GeoJSON file, and then creating a layer that uses the file as it's data source. There are a few online converters to convert a XLS or CSV to GeoJSON for your data source. I wrote up this for a class, it might help.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap1.html

I'm using circlemarkers instead of icons but it's very similar.

Comment: Hi Bill, Sorry kept getting  $ is not defined                             $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     Shelter.addData(data);
 });

Comment: my mistake I did not include a reference jquery

Comment: Got it working? I have other demo/ examples on that site if you want them.

Comment: No unfortunately not. Markers were not appearing.

Comment: Check your geojson file at http://geojsonlint.com/ to make sure it's not the format. Make sure the geojson file and the png are in the same folder as your html file. Are you opening the file through your web server software "http://localhost/folder/file.html" not just clicking on it. It needs the server to serve the geojson file. Lastly use F12 to open the console. A console.log(data); after the addData should show data. Is your data has to be in WGS84 (4326)?, Zoom all the way out to check. If you took my sample page and use your GeoJSON, comment out the popup stuff it should draw.

Comment: Got a marker displayed as default and not as the customised L.icon

Comment: L.marker([latlng],{icon: geoJSONMarkerOptions});   It should look something link this, if your looking at your how to instantiate Marker

Comment: https://indicator.extension.iastate.edu/projects/tasksheets/reports/PM2082-15e.pdf  or https://indicator.extension.iastate.edu/projects/tasksheets/reports/PM2082-17p.pdf  may help. More examples https://www.extension.iastate.edu/communities/gis/quicktasksheets search on Leaflet

Comment: Excellent thank you @Bill Chappell. Got it working with L.marker(latlng,{icon: geoJSONMarkerOptions});